# PHP preg_split: Split string by forward slash

Tags: php, string, preg-split

I want to split my string `192.168.1.1/24` by forward slash using PHP function **[preg_split](http://php.net/manual/fr/function.preg-split.php)**.

**My variable :**

```
$ip_address = "192.168.1.1/24";
```

**I have tried :**

```
preg_split("/\//", $ip_address); 
//And
preg_split("/[/]/", $ip_address);
```

> **Error message :** preg_split(): Delimiter must not be alphanumeric or backslash

I found the following answer here in stackoverflow **[Php preg_split for forwardslash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17775374/php-preg-split-for-forwardslash)**, but it not provide a direct answer.

Comment: `explode('/', "192.168.1.1/24")`

Comment: `preg_split("/\//", $ip_address);` should work fine. It does for me.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Just use another symbol as delimiter

```
$ip_address = "192.168.1.1/24";

$var = preg_split("#/#", $ip_address); 

print_r($var);
```

will output

```
Array
(
    [0] => 192.168.1.1
    [1] => 24
)
```

Comment: Not work for me:

var_dump(preg_split("#/#/#","12/34/5678"));

will return bool(false)

Comment: if you use it like this `var_dump(preg_split("#/#","12/34/5678"));` it will return the three strings separated by `/`

Comment: For fun - see https://www.php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.delimiters.php for the available delimiters.  e.g. `var_dump(preg_split("(/)", "192.168.1.1/24"))`.

Answer (score 6):

This is another way that meet up your solution

```
$ip_address = "192.168.1.1/24";
$var = preg_split("/\//", $ip_address);
print_r($var);
```

**Output result**

```
Array(
    [0] => 192.168.1.1
    [1] => 24
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `explode('/', "192.168.1.1/24");`

Comment: I'm sorry but I wanna use `preg_split` as described in my question _using PHP function preg_split._

Comment: Sorry, my bad. I was finding the way to split string and went to your question by google search. So I thought that you had the same problem with me. Sorry.